# Access IB Object from Custom Class

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, interface-builder, textview, subclass

This is a silly beginner question but... If I have a custom subclass of NSTextView "SSTextView" that spawns from Interface Builder, how do I access the instance of my custom class that is actually in the interface *from inside SSTextView.m*? The overall goal, I guess, is to be able to call an instance method in SSTextView.m from another method in the file. I know that `[self aMethod]` only works for class methods.

Now, I know I can do this from another class's implementation by using `IBOutlet SSTextView *myTextView;` and making the connections in Interface Builder, but it seems like an odd organizational paradigm that I wouldn't be able to put the methods that deal with my user interface text view in its own implementation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got this part backwards:

> I know that [self aMethod] only works for class methods.

`[self aMethod]` is how you invoke an instance method on the current object.

`[MyClass aMethod]` is how you invoke a class method.

Comment: Hmm, except for when I'm using `self` inside a class method. So really my question is, how do I call an instance method from inside a class method? It won't let me use any instance variables. I should mention that I'm only in a class method in the first place because I'm using NSThread's `detachNewThreadSelector:` method, which for some reason wants a class method.

Comment: Alright, never mind, I got it. Thanks for the help. I was specifying a class instead of a class instance for my `toTarget:aTarget`, so naturally a class method was expected.

Answer (score 2):

Did you actually tried `[self aMethod]`?

If you are in an instance method of SSTextView, you should be able to call an other instance method of SSTextView using `[self aMethod]`. As `self` is a pointer to the current class instance.